# Unregistered User with multiple accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed

A user that goes by the name "M.A. Golding" seems to be having issues, with constant account creation. They have 5? accounts, with a few decent answers between them.

User IDs: 34844 34846 34850 34852 that I could find.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: That issue can only be resolved by CM, so raised a Contact us flag for it. But i have doubts about this user if he will going to even stop after the merge or not.

Comment: Unregistered users can't be merged unless one of them registers an account. (This is also a problem on other sites, where there are up to 23 different "M.A. Golding" accounts.)

Comment: @randal'thor CM can merge unregistered account. And it already did.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/66793/m-a-golding